# set up HTTP authentication

Tags: php

I need to set up HTTP authentication. I'm lost, I've researched and found the technique and code to validate $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'], and I think I understand that. However I don't understand how to set PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW ? I used print-r on $_SERVER and didn't see either? Do I somehow set these in a file somewhere on the server, or do I set using code?

I'm on a shared server hosted by Webfaction.

I realize this might not be a great question, but if someone would point me in the right direction it would be great..

Comment: I can't understand if you don't know how to set valid user/pass values or how to let user input those values?

Comment: I don't understand how to set the value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's all the code you need:

```
$successful = FALSE;

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{
    $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    if ($username == '-- username --' && $password == '-- password --')
    {
        $successful = TRUE;
    }
}

if ( ! $successful)
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secret page"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
}
```

It would ask for username and password, see if they match and if they don't - ask for them again.

Note that, depending on server configuration, [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) may not work.

---

*p.s. You should replace `-- username --` and `-- password --` with username and password of your own.*

Comment: I guess I'm still confused - in your code you set $username to $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; which as I understand it is a  superglobals so we have a variable set to a superglobals variable then the IF statement tests if the $username is set to a value - but I still don't see where the $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] value is set?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Both `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` are global. They contain the username and the password provided by the user who attempts to access the page.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it, will go back and try again. Thanks for your help, I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how it works, and I think I'm slowly getting it..

Comment: turns out that this won't work on the server where I have my site hosted (webfaction) they gave me a work around that I'm trying. But I also now understand that the $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] is passing back what the user entered into the form - that was the part I was confused on...thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

When the page is called, `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is not set. So the page return header `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized` that show the modal on your browser.

And when the browser send se second request with ID and password. It send this request:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

And the super global vars `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` are automaticaly setted by PHP.

Sources:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 0):

To set an environment variable (aka superglobals), the format is:
$_SERVER['variable'] = value (or variable);

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php - good info on PHP superglobal variables.